# Регулярное выражение много строчное

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуй сообщество есть вот такая строка и регулярное выражение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так что бы только первый элемент парсилось только то что в начале строки без 2 этого вот кусочка?

Comment: regex101 не поддерживает синтаксис регулярных выражений Java, `(?U)` в  PCRE означает "ungreedy", переключает жадность.

Answer (score 2):

Всё оказалось просто нужно добавить символ начала строки)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы найти 0 и более любых букв + `;` в начале строки с помощью регулярного выражения Java, можно использовать

```
String regex = "^\\p{L}*;";
String regex = "(?m)^\\p{L}*;"; // (?m) для поддержки многострочности
```

Обратите внимание, что тут опция `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` (`(?U)`) не нужна, буквенный класс `\p{L}` поддерживает все буквы Юникода по умолчанию.

См. [демо на regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Lzevu2/1).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки (при использовании `(?m)` находит также позиции после символа перехода на новую строку)
- `\p{L}*` - ноль и более любых букв
- `;` - символ `;`.